# Висeлица на Java. Хорошо ли спроектировано?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Вопрос даже не вопрос, а, точнее сказать, просьба показать на мои возможные недочёты, предложить более грамотный код.

Класс `Game`:

```
public class Game {

    private int lifes = 5;
    private String secret;
    private List<Character> progress, mistakes;

    public void startGame(String word) {
        secret = word.toLowerCase();
        progress = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++) {
            progress.add('_');
        }
        mistakes = new ArrayList<Character>();
        printProgress();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (input.length() != 1 || !Character.isLetter(input.charAt(0))) {
                System.out.print("Введите букву: ");
                continue;
            }
            char userVariant = input.charAt(0);
            if (mistakes.contains(userVariant) || progress.contains(userVariant)) {
                System.out.println("Эта буква уже была");
                System.out.print("Введите букву: ");
                continue;
            }
            List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = secret.indexOf(userVariant); index >= 0; index = secret.indexOf(userVariant, index + 1)) {
                progress.set(index, userVariant);
                indexes.add(index);
            }
            if (indexes.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("Неправильно! ");
                mistakes.add(userVariant);
                lifes--;
                if (lifes == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nВы проиграли...");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("Правильно! ");
                boolean playerWin = true;
                for (Character letter : progress) {
                    if (!Character.isLetter(letter)) {
                        playerWin = false;
                    }
                }
                if (playerWin) {
                    System.out.println("Вы выйграли!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            printProgress();
        } 
        System.out.println("Это было слово: " + secret.toUpperCase());
    }

    private void printProgress() {
        System.out.print("Слово:");
        for (char letter : progress) {
            System.out.print(" " + letter);
        }
        System.out.print("\nЖизни: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < lifes; i++) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n\nВведите букву: ");
    }
}
```

Класс `WordGenerator`:

```
public class WordGenerator {

    private String[] words = {
        "пальто", "одиночество", "лопата",
        "коромысло", "леопард"
    };

    public String generateWord() {
        return words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)];
    }
}
```

Класс `Main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordGenerator wordGen = new WordGenerator();
        while (true) {
            String word = wordGen.generateWord();
            Game game = new Game();
            game.startGame(word);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Хотите сыграть ещё раз? +/-");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.isEmpty()) continue;
                char answer = input.charAt(0);
                if (answer == '+') {
                    break;
                } else if (answer == '-') {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Из комментариев выведены главные недостатки

> Я бы очень избегал применения слов `break` и `continue`. Попробуйте по-другому построить логику.
>
> Непонятно, почему сама игра в классе Game, а опрос на продолжение вынесен в Main. Можно точно так же сделать его в Game.
>
> startGame() тоже неплохо бы разделить на отдельные методы. Например, напрашивается на отдельный метод проверка на наличие буквы.

При переносе опроса в игру возникли трудности, например, как я получу новое слово, если генератор в майне? Символ неугаданной буквы вынесен в константу (чтобы его можно было при необходимости быстро поменять, не бегая по всему коду). Также подготовка переменных к игре выведена в конструктор. Думаю, так логичнее.

Обновленный класс `Main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordGenerator wordGen = new WordGenerator();
        Game currentGame = null;
        while (true) {
            String word = wordGen.generateWord();
            currentGame = new Game(word);
            currentGame.startGame();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Хотите сыграть ещё раз? +/-");
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.length() == 1) {
                    char answer = input.charAt(0);
                    if (answer == '-') System.exit(0);
                    if (answer == '+') break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Обновленный класс `Game`:

```
public class Game {

    private static final char LETTER_MASK = '_';
    private int lifes = 5;
    private String secret;
    private List<Character> progress, mistakes;

    public Game(String word) {
        secret = word.toLowerCase();
        progress = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++) {
            progress.add(LETTER_MASK);
        }
        mistakes = new ArrayList<Character>();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        printProgress();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (input.length() != 1 || !Character.isLetter(input.charAt(0))) {
                System.out.print("Введите букву: ");
            } else {
                char userVariant = input.charAt(0);
                if (mistakes.contains(userVariant) || progress.contains(userVariant)) {
                    System.out.println("Эта буква уже была");
                    System.out.print("Введите букву: ");
                } else {
                    if (checkGuess(userVariant)) {
                        System.out.print("Правильно! ");
                        if (!progress.contains(LETTER_MASK)) {
                            System.out.println("Вы выйграли!");
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Неправильно! ");
                        mistakes.add(userVariant);
                        if (--lifes == 0) {
                            System.out.println("\nВы проиграли...");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    printProgress();
                }
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("Это было слово: " + secret.toUpperCase());
    }

    private boolean checkGuess(char userVariant) {
        boolean guessed = false;
        for (int index = secret.indexOf(userVariant); index >= 0; index = secret.indexOf(userVariant, index + 1)) {
            progress.set(index, userVariant);
            guessed = true;
        }
        return guessed;
    }

    private void printProgress() {
        System.out.print("Слово:");
        for (char letter : progress) {
            System.out.print(" " + letter);
        }
        System.out.print("\nЖизни: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < lifes; i++) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n\nВведите букву: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверяли инвариантные культуры? Straße и Strasse?

Comment: @Anamnian, не понял) если вы про циклы, то думаю с ними нет проблем

Comment: @Anamnian Тут нет никаких инвариантов. Правильно только Straße. А если мы играем в Швейцарии, то там нет ß.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что слова только русские будут)

Comment: @Flippy понятно.

Comment: А зачем вот эта переменная `List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();`? Мне кажется вам она тут не нужна.

Comment: @Anamnian, я ее использую чтобы после поиска всех индексов проверить было ли хоть одно совпадение. Впринципе я могу ее заменить `boolean` флагом типа `boolean guessed = false` и ставить ей true в цикле

Comment: Непонятно, почему сама игра в классе Game, а опрос на продолжение вынесен в Main. Можно точно так же сделать его в Game. Класс WordGenerator тоже особо не нужен. Разве что для тренировки. Почему "вы выиграли" с "й", а "вы проиграли" с "и"? Это однокоренные слова и пишутся они одинаково.

Comment: Я бы очень избегал применения слов `break` и `continue`. Попробуйте по-другому построить логику.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я почему-то подумал, что опрос не относится к самой игре... Про однокоренные слова я даже и не подумал :) Окей, исправлю, я так понял Е/Ё тоже

Comment: @Эникейщик, я подумал, что генерация слов с уклоном "на будущее" будет происходить с обращением в Интернет или еще как-то.

Comment: @Эникейщик Насчет генератора - потом можно сделать Extract Interface и подсунуть другую реализацию, например, выбор слова из БД

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Согласен.

Comment: Согласен про continue и break, анализаторы позволяют использовать только одно из этих слов в цикле и только в одном месте.

Comment: ``startGame()`` тоже неплохо бы разделить на отдельные методы. Например, напрашивается на отдельный метод проверка на наличие буквы.

Comment: @Maxim, а как же мне быть без них?) не, ну я могу заменить `continue`на действие по обратному условию, но возрастет вложенность кода в этих лесенках

Comment: @Эникейщик, точно! Метод `checkGuess`. Я думал об этом, привязался к `indexes` коллекции. Уже понял что она не нужна (см. выше)

Comment: @Flippy делите на более мелкие методы и обыгрывайте через return